# How can I import fish previous version of prompt to newer versions?

Tags: command-line, prompt, fish

I don't know what happened to the prompt Classic + Git Prompt that Fish used to have in the list of prompts available.

In any case I have another machine using an older version of Fish that it does have it, so I was wondering how I can export it to the newer version and why that prompt got deleted instead of increase the number of prompts in newer versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This prompt is still available, but it has been renamed to 'Classic + Vcs' because it now supports git, Mercurial and svn. You should be able to see it in the `fish_config` prompt chooser.

You can always see your prompt function by running:

```
functions fish_prompt
```

(Note function**s**, not function)

Comment: thank you @ridiculous_fish and then if I want to create a new prompt, where should I do that?

Comment: You should create a `fish_prompt` function in a file named `fish_prompt.fish` and put it in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fish/functions/` (usually expands to `~/.config/fish/functions`). From then on it will be auto-loaded and used to define your prompt. You also have `fish_right_prompt`, `fish_mode_prompt`, `fish_greeting` and `fish_title` to customize if you'd like. More details can be found in the docs on the official website. http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#other